# Sampling a Greyscale image into 8 levels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

**What I am trying to do:-**

Using MATLAB, I am trying to read a Greyscale image (having pixel values bw range 0-255) i.e. an 8bit image into like 3 bit image, hence it is like sampling the range into 8 different levels. For example if the pixel value is 25 then as it comes bw range 0-31, it will be assigned value 0, for bw 32-63 level will be 1 and so on until finally range 224-255 it will be on range 7.

After that I am counting the total no of pixels in different levels.

**Code:-**

```
img=imread('Cameraman.bmp');
r=size(img,1);
c=size(img,2);
pixel_count=zeros(9,1);
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        if fix(img(i,j)/31)==8
            img(i,j)
        end
        img(i,j)=fix(img(i,j)/33);
        pixel_count(img(i,j)+1)=pixel_count(img(i,j)+1)+1;
    end
end
pixel_count
```

**My Problem:-**

Even if the range of each pixel is from 0-255, and I am dividing it into 8 levels, I am getting a total of 9 levels.

For debugging it I added the `if statement` in the code and my output is:--

```
ans = 248
ans = 250
ans = 249
ans = 249
ans = 235
ans = 249
ans = 249
ans = 235
...and more
pixel_count =

   11314
    3741
    2061
    5284
   12629
   25590
    4439
     437
      41
```

As you can see for some values like 249,235 and more I am getting the extra 9th level.

What is the problem here. Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: what is the result of `max(img(:))`?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez - If it's `uint8`, then it should be 255.  Anything larger will saturate so there isn't a way to generate values beyond that much.. besides which, the OP is dividing by the wrong coefficient to get the right bin.

Comment: it should be, indeed. I noticed the wrong coefficient (it should be 32), but with 33 it should still only produce 8 bins.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez - Correct you are about that!

Comment: @zeeMonkeez As `img` is like 2D matrix, I am getting a whole row of 256 values as output with no element more than 255.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is the goal to get the image to 8 levels or to generate the histogram?

Comment: @Mohit Your problem is that `img` is `uint8` data. Division by a double will round, so e.g. `253/32 == 9` if `253` is `uint`.

Comment: @breaker yeah mainly thats the reason. But my teacher told me to do so without using histrogram related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't dividing by the right value properly.  You need to divide by **32**, then take the `floor` / `fix`.  Between 0-31, if you divide by 32 then take the `floor` / `fix`, you get the value 0, between 31-63, you get 1, up until 224-255 which gives you 7.

Also, your `for` loop is incorrect.  You are mistakenly replacing the pixel of the input image with its bin location.  I would also change the precision to `double`.  It seems that with my experiments, using `fix` combined with a `uint8` image gives me that random 9th bin index that you're talking about.

Take a look at some sample results from my REPL:

```
>> fix(240/32) + 1

ans =

     8

>> fix(uint8(240)/32) + 1

ans =

    9

>> fix(uint8(255)/32) + 1

ans =

    9

>> fix(255/32) + 1

ans =

     8
```

Therefore, it's a problem with the image type.  For any values that are beyond 240, the value when being divided by 32 as it's `uint8` gets **rounded** so that `240 / 32 = 7.5` but because it's `uint8` and it's an integer, it gets rounded to 8, then adding 1 makes it go to 9.  Therefore, anything beyond 240 will get rounded to 8 and ultimately giving you 9 when adding by 1.

So, simply change the division to be 32, not 33 or 31 and fix what I said above:

```
img=imread('Cameraman.bmp');
img = double(img); %// Change
r=size(img,1);
c=size(img,2);
pixel_count=zeros(8,1); %// Change
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        pix = fix(img(i,j)/32); %// Change here
        pixel_count(pix+1)=pixel_count(pix+1) + 1; %// Change
    end
end
pixel_count
```

As a minor note, to check to see if you're right, use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
pixel_count = histc(fix(double(img(:))/32) + 1, 1:8);
```

If you got your code right, your code and with what I wrote above should match.  Using the `cameraman.tif` image that's built-in to the Image Processing Toolbox, let's compare the outputs:

```
>> pixel_count
pixel_count =

       13532
        2500
        2104
        8341
       15333
       22553
         817
         356

>> pixel_count2 = histc(fix(double(img(:))/32) + 1, 1:8)

pixel_count2 =

       13532
        2500
        2104
        8341
       15333
       22553
         817
         356
```

Looks good to me!

Comment: That was what I was doing before, still tried it again, no change in answer. I am still getting the 9th level pixel count = 41

Comment: @Mohit - You sure?  It works for me.  Let me check again.

Comment: Sorry, a little edit for the above comment, now the no of elements in level 9 are 114...

Comment: @Mohit - I figured it out.  It's a problem with the image type.  Try **casting** the image to `double`, then try again.  I've also edited my post.

Comment: @Mohit - No problem. Good luck!